# Error Exception 2048 on my website using OpenClassifieds software

Tags: php

I have a website called e-waitress.net, it is a jobs employment website for the restaurant industry. I installed an open source program called OpenClassifieds and a couple days after installing the OpenClassifieds, I get an error message when I enter my url that is this:

> ErrorException [ 2048 ]: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead ~ APPPATH/ko322/classes/kohana/date.php [ 592 ]

I am wondering is this a server issue with my host provider or is it within the OpenClassifieds installation software? I've reinstalled the software twice and it's returned this error after a couple days of working great.

Any ideas?

Comment: Err... did you set the "date.timezone" setting in your php.ini?

Comment: Also, [try this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=It+is+not+safe+to+rely+on+the+system%27s+timezone+settings) `;-)`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I did call my webhost at 1and1.com who walked me through making a php.ini file specifying default timezone which I uploaded to the folder containing the OpenClassifieds files on my website, Thanks very much! I would have thought that this would be specified as automatic, but as you might be able to tell, I am a complete newbie when it comes to PHP matters  :)

Comment: You're welcome, Rich. If you can get into the habit of searching for error messages, it's a very useful trick in one's armoury `:)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, being totally new to matters in PHP brought me here to stackoverflow and yes, simply uploading a php.ini file to the folder where the OpenClassifieds is hosted solved the problem for me.